# Json to XML tool?

Tags: xml, json

I have one json file but an application that I use imports data only from xml files. So does somebody know of a tool that converts json files to xml?  I've been looking for such tool for a few hours and could only find tools that create json files from xml.

Thanks!

Comment: See this question for a XSLT converter (quite cool): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559296/java-implementation-of-json-to-xml-conversion

Comment: Obviously the problem with JSON->XML conversion is JSON does not differentiate attributes, values and subelements, so there's no one to one mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the .NET Framework, you can do this in code:

- Create a JSON reader over your JSON content using the JsonReaderWriterFactory class
- Create a regular XmlWriter, and call WriteNode on it giving it the JSON reader. It will write out XML corresponding to your JSON.

Caveats:

- This will use a Microsoft-proprietary JSON-to-XML mapping (there isn't a standard one). The XML will look strange.
- There were some serious bugs blocking this scenario in .NET3.5. Maybe fixed in .NET 3.5 SP1, maybe fixed in 4.0, fixed for sure in Silverlight 3

Answer (score 0):

**A pure XSLT 2.0 implementation**:

Have a look at the [**`f:json-document()`**](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-json-document.xsl?view=markup&sortby=date) from the [**FXSL 2.x library**](http://fxsl.sf.net).

Using this function it is extremely easy to incorporate JSon and use it just as... XML.

For example, one can just write the following XPath expression:

```
f:json-document($vstrParam)/Students/*[sex = 'Female']
```

and **get all children of `Students` with `sex = 'Female'`**

**Here is the complete example:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f xs"
 >
 <xsl:import href="../f/func-json-document.xsl"/>

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vstrParam" as="xs:string">
{

  "teacher":{
    "name":
      "Mr Borat",
    "age":
      "35",
    "Nationality":
      "Kazakhstan"
             },


  "Class":{
    "Semester":
      "Summer",
    "Room":
      null,
    "Subject":
      "Politics",
    "Notes":
      "We're happy, you happy?"
           },

  "Students":
    {
      "Smith":
        {"First Name":"Mary","sex":"Female"},
      "Brown":
        {"First Name":"John","sex":"Male"},
      "Jackson":
        {"First Name":"Jackie","sex":"Female"}
    }
    ,


  "Grades":

    {
      "Test":
      [
        {"grade":"A","points":68,"grade":"B","points":25,"grade":"C","points":15},

        {"grade":"C","points":2, "grade":"B","points":29, "grade":"A","points":55},

        {"grade":"C","points":2, "grade":"A","points":72, "grade":"A","points":65}
       ]
    }


}
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
     "f:json-document($vstrParam)/Students/*[sex = 'Female']"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on any XML document (ignored), the correct result is produced**:

```
<Smith>
   <First_Name>Mary</First_Name>
   <sex>Female</sex>
</Smith>
<Jackson>
   <First_Name>Jackie</First_Name>
   <sex>Female</sex>
</Jackson>
```