# Translating JSON to Xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, json, angularjs, xslt, architecture

Is it possible to translate JSON to XML using existing XSLT templates?
I do not want to have another layer of xml transformation `JSON->XML->XSLT->Final XML`.
Reason being that I am writing a new UI for a legacy system replacing it FlexUI. Current UI sends xml requests and gets xml response.
I am emphasizing on JSON objects so that I can take advantage latest MVVM frameworks like AngularJS or Backbone.js.

> I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? (See Michael Kay's comment in the answer below.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert json to xml using xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007280/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-using-xslt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT on the client can do it via JavaScript libraries:

- json2xml.js + SAXON CE
- json2xml.js + Stapling

XSLT on the server can do it via XSLT 2.0 libraries:

- FXSL 2.0

Or you can do it on the client by reading the JSON file via:

- an external entity defined in the DTD
- an external parameter defined in the XSLT processor initialization

then parsing it using string methods.

**References**

- [XSLT FAQ: Comma Separated Data](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N1755.html)
- [Converting Between XML and JSON](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1658)
- [Interactive XSLT in the Browser](http://balisage.net/Proceedings/vol10/html/Delpratt01/BalisageVol10-Delpratt01.html)
- [Saxon-CE Github Repo](https://github.com/Saxonica/Saxon-CE)
- [extracting information from a JSON file using XSLT version 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188064/extracting-information-from-a-json-file-using-xslt-version-1-0)
- [Stapling Github Repo](https://github.com/WelcomWeb/Stapling)
- [Json to XML tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528819/json-to-xml-tool/5863688#5863688)
- [Passing and accessing parameters in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356113/passing-and-accessing-parameters-in-xslt/23555591#23555591)