# Passing and accessing parameters in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, parameters

I have an XML on which I am displaying the test cases as HTML using XSLT.

I have one query.

How to pass a variable as a parameter and access it on the other page.

So far I achieved this:

```
               <xsl:for-each select="//test-suite[@type='TestFixture']">
                <tr>      
                    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(@result, 'Success')">
                    <xsl:variable name="nameOfPage" select="@name" />
                <td><a href="DownloadManagerFeature.xml?nameOfPage={$nameOfPage}" style="text-decoration: none" ><font color="239625"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></font></a></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@result"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@time"/></td>
                    </xsl:when>
```

As you can see, I am setting the value of `name` parameter to `nameOfPage` and 
I am passing it as a URL parameter.

But I am facing some issues retrieving it on other page.

```
 <td>test page</td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="@nameOfPage"/></td>
```

The value is coming as null.
I even added this at the top:

```
<xsl:variable name="nameOfPage" select="document('Mimedrive.Tests.xml')"/>
```

I am trying to match the nameOfPage to the @name in the case.
When I do it with hardcoded values its working , like:

```
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="//test-case">
                    <xsl:if test="contains(@name, 'XXX.DownloadManagerFeature')">
                <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@description"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@result"/></td>
                </tr>
```

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by other page? Can you rephrase your question with more details about your usecase. In addition, can you provide a sample xml. Also what version of XSLT you are using (1 or 2) and what transformation implementation you are using?

Comment: Why do you use both `@name` and `nameOfPage`? After the variable assignment they should be equal. And what is `<xsl:variable name="nameOfPage" select="document('Mimedrive.Tests.xml')"/>` supposed to do? If you want to assign a constant string containing the name of an XML file use `<xsl:variable name="nameOfPage" select="'Mimedrive.Tests.xml'"/>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript binding of XSLT to set the `nameOfPage` parameter before processing.

Assuming the XML document has the XHTML namespace as the default, then:

```
function transform()
  {
  var nameOfPage = var value=RegExp("nameOfPage[^&]+").exec(window.location.search)[0].replace(/[^=]+./,"");

  with (new XSLTProcessor)
     {
     setParameter(null, "nameOfPage", nameOfPage);
     importStylesheet("foo.xsl");
     transform.result = transformToFragment(this, document);
     transform.root = transform.result.xml;
     document.getElementById(appendTo).appendChild(transform.root);
     }
  }
```

Or use the processor specific processing instruction, as in Firefox:

```
<?xslt-param name="nameOfPage" value="foo"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="foo.xsl"?>
```

Or use the processor specific `setParameter` method, for instance PHP:

```
$transformer  = new XSLTProcessor();
$transformer->importStylesheet("foo.xsl");
$transformer->setParameter('', 'nameOfPage', $_POST['nameOfPage']);
```

**References**

- [PI Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/PI_Parameters)
- [Setting Parameters for XSLTProcessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_XSLT_JavaScript_Interface_in_Gecko/Setting_Parameters)
- [XSLTProcessor::setParameter](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php)
- [Saxon:Running a Transformation from the command line](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.5/using-xsl.html)
- [Saxon:setParams](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.1/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/Transform.html#setParams)
- [How to Write CGI Applications in Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239588)