# how to create xml

Tags: android, xml, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java implementation of JSON to XML conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559296/java-implementation-of-json-to-xml-conversion)
>   [Simplest method to Convert Json to Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742705/simplest-method-to-convert-json-to-xml)

I want to change this `json` to `xml`, I don't know how to create `xml` for the same, please someone show me some code how can I change this `json` to `xml`:--
`json` code is:-

```
  {
     "pizza": [{
         "title": "Pizza Item 1",
         "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit",
         "cost": "$0.00",
         "imageUri": "http://www.pizzahut.com.au/images/menu/Pizza-Lge-BBQ_Meatlovers.png"
     }, {
         "title": "Pizza Item 2",
         "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit",
         "cost": "$0.00",
         "imageUri": "http://www.pizzahut.com.au/images/menu/Pizza-Lge-BBQ_Meatlovers.png"
     }],
     "cake": [{
         "title": "Cake Item 1",
         "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit",
         "cost": "$0.00",
         "imageUri": "http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/cake4.jpg"
     }, {
         "title": "Cake Item 2",
         "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit",
         "cost": "$0.00",
         "imageUri": "http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/cake4.jpg"
     }, {
         "title": "Cake Item 3",
         "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit",
         "cost": "$0.00",
         "imageUri": "http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/cake4.jpg"
     }]
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559296/java-implementation-of-json-to-xml-conversion

Comment: please write few lines of code only, then i can understand easily, like in above json i have two parent nodes namely - pizza,cake and i have child attributes under these nodes,just show me if i want to write this code into xml file how i need to write,thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this online converter via google. Hope it helps

http://jsontoxml.utilities-online.info/

once converted add 
    doc 
at the beginning and /doc at the end with the brackets.

On the second line include some type of .css format to display the xml and presto :)