# JSON to XML with type attribute in java

Tags: java, c#, json, xml, parsing

I'm rewriting C# application into java code.

There is REST API which return jsons.
I have to parse json to XML but C# library and Java doing it in difference ways.

**How to keep type= attribute in java?** I can't use JAXB annotations becouse there are too many objects in response and they might changing. XML.toString(jsonObject) doesn't work for me.

C# parsing is done in this way:

```
XDocument.load(JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString), new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()));
```

C# result:

```
<root type="object">   
  <Items type="array">
    <item type="object">
      <Name type="string">test</Name>
      <Total type="number">12.8000000</Total>
      <CurrencyCode type="string">CHF</CurrencyCode>
      <Country type="string">CH</Country>
    </item>   
  </Items> 
</root>
```

Java result:

```
<root>
  <Items> 
    <item> 
      <Name>test</Name> 
      <Total>12.8000000</Total> 
      <CurrencyCode>CHF</CurrencyCode> 
      <Country>CH</Country>> 
    </item>   
 </Items>
</root>
```

Comment: This may help [Json-to-xml-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742705/simplest-method-to-convert-json-to-xml)

Comment: Underscore-java library can convert json to xml. U.jsonToXml(json) method will help.

Answer (score 0):

I've used org.w3c.Document and  org.w3c.dom.Element and set up attribute "type".
Anyway thanks for help :)