# convert json which escaped quotes to xml

Tags: java, json, xml

i have the following json-string:

```
{result:{"id":"1234","pages": [{"Id":50,"data":"{\"name\":\"name1\",\"description\":\"description1\"}"}],"errors":[] }}
```

which i want to convert to xml. I have tried several methods to convert, one of which is decribed here: [Java implementation of JSON to XML conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559296/java-implementation-of-json-to-xml-conversion) :

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String xml = org.json.XML.toString(o);
```

the result of this is:

```
<result><id>1234</id><pages><data>{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;name1&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;description1&quot;}</data><Id>50</Id></pages></result>
```

or formatted:

```
<result>
  <id>1234</id>
  <pages>
    <Id>50</Id>
    <data>{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;name1&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;description1&quot;}</data>
  </pages>
</result>
```

obviously the data in 'data' is converted to a string. Actually what I want is a structure like this, where the content of the 'data' block is converted to tags:

```
<result>
  <id>1234</id>
  <pages>
    <Id>50</Id>
    <data>
      <name>name1</name>
      <description>description1</description>
    </data>
  </pages>
</result>
```

i know this was the result if the json string would be

```
{result:{"id":"1234","pages": [{"Id":50,"data":{"name":"name1","description":"description1"}}],"errors":[]}}
```

but unfortunatelly i can not change that.

So does anyone know about a method to convert

```
{result:{"id":"1234","pages": [{"Id":50,"data":"{\"name\":\"name1\",\"description\":\"description1\"}"}],"errors":[] }}
```

to

```
<result>
  <id>1234</id>
  <pages>
    <Id>50</Id>
    <data>
      <name>name1</name>
      <description>description1</description>
    </data>
  </pages>
</result>
```

in java?

Comment: You need to find the field `data` in your `JSONObject`, and convert it again to a `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well escaping the quotes means they are escaped and the string is no longer json.
What you are trying to do is not within any kind of json standard - so you have to fix the problem yourself ;-)

How about this:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(jsonString.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\""));
String xml = org.json.XML.toString(o);
```

**Update** - there are many more problems - this will work:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(
jsonString.replaceFirst("result", "\"result\"")
.replaceAll("\"\\{", "{")
.replaceAll("\\}\"", "}")
.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"") );
String xml = org.json.XML.toString(o);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have tried that before, but

using `replaceAll("\\\"", "\"")` results in
`<result><id>1234</id><pages><data>{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;name1&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;description1&quot;}</data><Id>50</Id></pages><pages><data>{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;name2&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;description2&quot;}</data><Id>51</Id></pages></result>`

using `replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"")` results in an exception

org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 51 [character 52 line 1]

Comment: My code sample was correct, but there are more problems:
1) the data object is surrounded by quotes that have to be removed after unescaping
2) the "result" key is not surrounded by quotes - they must be added.
I have updated my code sample above with a fix for both.

Comment: Btw. I have used a json validator to track down these additional isses. Might be helpful for you as well: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: you are right, this works. i am not (yet) fully familiar with json syntax, so i did not spot these 'details'. thank you very much!