# How to convert Badgerfish style JSON to XML in Java?

Tags: java, json, xml, gson

My Java application takes XML input, and parses it using  the simpleframework. I want it to accept JSON as well, therefore I want to convert the JSON to XML.

Tags and attributes are important, therefore I use the Badgerfish convention. 
This works well in Python with [xmljson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmljson), but I can't find a decent package to do this. GSON doesn't seem to have a Badgerfish implementation. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559296/java-implementation-of-json-to-xml-conversion) topic doesn't provide any tag/attribute retaining packages, the topic is a bit old as well.

Which Java packages can do the conversion from JSON to XML while putting tags/attributes at the right place?

Suggestions for alternative methods than Badgerfish are welcome as well...

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the XPath 3.1 `json-to-xml()` function, and then do an XSLT transformation on the generated XML to get it into the format you require.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've been trying and searching quite a bit but I can't figure out which package implements these functions. Or is it implemented in the standard Java libraries?

To be honest: I'm quite new to Java...

Comment: XPath 3.1 is implemented in recent versions of Saxon, and by a few other libraries such as BaseX.

Comment: Note, as far as I can see Badgerfish concentrates on ensuring that for every XML document, there is a defined JSON representation. The XPath conversion functions concentrate on ensuring that for every JSON document, there is a defined XML representation. This means that with the Badgerfish conventions, there will be JSON documents that don't translate to XML (e.g. `{"name with space":true()}`, while with the XPath convention, there will be XML documents that can't be converted to JSON. So the two are suited for rather different purposes.

Comment: I was not aware of XPath and XSLT. I learned how to use it, and for me this works much better than the badgerfish conversion.