# Converting JSON to XMl file

Tags: json

What will be the preferred way of converting JSON to XML file? Is it better to use web-service or any Java component? I tried using web-service and still wanted to cross-check if there is any other option to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java implementation of JSON to XML conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559296/java-implementation-of-json-to-xml-conversion)

Comment: Welcome to SO Ravindra, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask "good" questions.

Comment: Please indicate what solutions you would accept, i.e. Are PHP solutions admissible, Javascript, etc etc.

Comment: The solution should be related to Java EE stack Or from Spring (open-source) stack i.e., the solution should use Java EE libraries Or it should use  Spring framework libraries only.

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.jsonToXml(json).

Answer (score 0):

Convert JSON text contained in string json into an XML node

```
XmlDocument Xmldoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
```

Here is the documentation:
[Json to xml](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm)