# how to convert arbitrary JSON to XML using BaseX?

Tags: java, json, xml, converters, basex

How is arbitrary `JSON` converted [to](http://docs.basex.org/javadoc/org/basex/io/parse/json/JsonConverter.html) arbitrary `XML` using `BaseX`?

I'm looking at `JsonParser` from `BaseX` for this [specific](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/io/parse/json/JsonParser.java) solution.

In this case, I [have](https://github.com/THUFIR/twitterBaseX) tweets using `Twitter4J`:

```
package twitterBaseX;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import main.LoadProps;
import org.basex.core.BaseXException;
import twitter4j.JSONException;
import twitter4j.JSONObject;
import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.TwitterObjectFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class TwitterOps {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TwitterOps.class.getName());

    public TwitterOps() {
    }

    private TwitterFactory configTwitterFactory() throws IOException {
        LoadProps loadTwitterProps = new LoadProps("twitter");
        Properties properties = loadTwitterProps.loadProperties();
        log.fine(properties.toString());
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        configurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setJSONStoreEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey(properties.getProperty("oAuthConsumerKey"))
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(properties.getProperty("oAuthConsumerSecret"))
                .setOAuthAccessToken(properties.getProperty("oAuthAccessToken"))
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(properties.getProperty("oAuthAccessTokenSecret"));

        return new TwitterFactory(configurationBuilder.build());
    }

    public List<JSONObject> getTweets() throws TwitterException, IOException, JSONException {
        Twitter twitter = configTwitterFactory().getInstance();

        Query query = new Query("lizardbill");
        QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
        String string = null;
        JSONObject tweet = null;
        List<JSONObject> tweets = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
            tweet = jsonOps(status);
            tweets.add(tweet);
        }
        return tweets;
    }

    private JSONObject jsonOps(Status status) throws JSONException, BaseXException {
        String string = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(string);
        String language = json.getString("lang");
        log.fine(language);
        return json;
    }

}
```

The `JSONObject` from `Twitter4J` cannot just get jammed into `XML`?

There are a number of [online converters](https://www.convertjson.com/json-to-xml.htm) which purport to accomplish this, and, which, at least at first glance, seem quite adequate.

see also:

[Converting JSON to XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19977979/262852)

[Java implementation of JSON to XML conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/559296/262852)

Answer (score 1):

Use the (excellent) JSON-Java library from json.org then

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```

`toString` can take a second argument to provide the name of the XML root node.

This library is also able to convert XML to JSON using `XML.toJSONObject(java.lang.String string)`

Check the [Javadoc](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html) for more information

Comment: thanks, I'm looking at:  https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/io/parse/json/JsonParser.java    to use just just that library.