# How to get a File or Stream from a JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, xml, twitter4j, basex

How is a `JSONObject` from `Twitter4J` converted to an `IOFile` for use with the `JsonParser` from `BaseX`?

So, looking to use `Twitter4J` to get either a file or stream.

The `JsonParser` looks to [work with](http://docs.basex.org/javadoc/org/basex/build/json/JsonParser.html) a `File` fine:

```
JsonParser

public JsonParser(IO source,
          MainOptions opts,
          JsonParserOptions jopts)
           throws java.io.IOException

Constructor.

Parameters:
    source - document source
    opts - database options
    jopts - parser options
Throws:
    java.io.IOException - I/O exception
```

although other `IO` works:

```
org.basex.io
Class IO

    java.lang.Object
        org.basex.io.IO 

    Direct Known Subclasses:
        IOContent, IOFile, IOStream, IOUrl
```

How is a `File` acquired from a `JSONObject` here?

[Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60015101/262852) using `Twitter4J`:

```
private JSONObject jsonOps(Status status) throws JSONException, BaseXException {
    String string = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(string);
    String language = json.getString("lang");
    log.fine(language);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think a File is, or can be, “acquired”? And why do you want a File when working with a Twitter feed?

Comment: I'm trying to convert to String, then writing to a File for BaseX, which requires a File.

Comment: How about converting the object to a string and writing that string to a file?

Comment: yes @Bohemian that's what I've done just now.  and then I'm now working on loading the file from `JsonParser` -- but that just seems silly from the outset.  I just want to send "json" to the `JsonParser`.

Comment: Use a stream? A `ByteArrayInputStream` from the String specifically.

Comment: I'm not sure I asked the question properly, @Kayaman, but yes, I used a stream as in the answer.

Comment: @Thufir yes, but I meant without writing to a `File` first. I'm pretty sure `JSonParser` can read from an `InputStream`, and you can get a `ByteArrayInputStream` from `String.getBytes(charset)`. Or a `Reader` and a `StringReader`. Ah, Basic IO, why have you been forgotten.

Comment: It's that BaseX library that's throwing things off, but no, you do not need to store things to a file and read them back that you already have in the memory.

Comment: Yeah, my "solution" is more than a bit smelly -- but works so far as I can tell, in that the parser is instantiated.  I'll come back to this in a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Writing a `JSONObject` to file file from `Twitter4J` seems to work, at least the file looks correct when opened manually:

```
public void writeJsonToFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = null;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, "UTF-8");
    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
    bufferedWriter.write(tweets.toString());
    bufferedWriter.close();
    outputStreamWriter.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

And once the file is written, it seems quite easy to "parse" the `JSON`, or at least instantiate a parser, as:

```
private void parseJsonFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser(new IOFile(fileName), new MainOptions());
}
```

full code on [github](https://github.com/THUFIR/twitterBaseX).

In no way is this a complete solution.  In fact, it seems a kludge to write the `JSON` to a file at all -- but there it is.

Seems the only way to move `JSON` data from `Twitter4J` to `BaseX`, or at least most pragmatic.  Other solutions appreciated.