# validating conversion of JSON to XML

Tags: java, json, xml, twitter4j, basex

While the `JSON` is [correctly](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html) formatted (the `jsonTweet` variable):

> The JSON input is valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specfication).
>   Close
>
> The JSON input is valid in JavaScript.

However, the `xml` output is [obviously](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/THUFIR/af13128364b8ac520e99afc62c8f6385/raw/8bd8562f6b6b727cb2016dd855c1dcd92fa3aae5/crash) invalid (as `xmlStringTweet` isn't `xml` at all).

The key lines, as it were:

```
        JSONObject jsonTweet = tweets.getJSONObject(Long.toString(id));
        xmlStringTweet = XML.toString(jsonTweet);
```

where the `jsonTweet` is [found by](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/twitter-ids) the "snowflake" id, and, then, [ostensibly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60015101/262852), converted to an `xml` string.

full code:

```
package basex;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.basex.core.BaseXException;
import org.basex.core.Context;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Add;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Open;
import org.basex.core.cmd.CreateDB;
import org.basex.core.cmd.DropDB;
import org.basex.core.cmd.List;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Set;
import org.json.XML;
import twitter4j.JSONException;
import twitter4j.JSONObject;

public class DatabaseHelper {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseHelper.class.getName());
    private Properties properties = new Properties();
    private URL url = null;
    private String databaseName = null;
    private Context context = null;
    private String parserType = null;

    private DatabaseHelper() {
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    private void init() throws MalformedURLException, BaseXException {
        log.fine(properties.toString());
        parserType = properties.getProperty("parserType");
        url = new URL(properties.getProperty(parserType + "URL"));
        databaseName = properties.getProperty("databaseName");
        context = new Context();
        list();
    }

    private void drop() throws BaseXException {
        new Set("parser", parserType).execute(context);
        new DropDB(databaseName).execute(context);
        list();
    }

    private void add(JSONObject tweets) throws JSONException, BaseXException {
        long id = 0L;
        Iterator keys = tweets.keys();
        String xmlStringTweet = null;
        new Open(databaseName).execute(context);
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            id = Long.parseLong(keys.next().toString());
            JSONObject jsonTweet = tweets.getJSONObject(Long.toString(id));
            xmlStringTweet = XML.toString(jsonTweet);
            log.info(Long.toString(id));
            log.info(jsonTweet.toString());
            log.info(xmlStringTweet);
            new Add(null, xmlStringTweet).execute(context);
        }
    }

    private void create() throws BaseXException, JSONException {
        new Set("parser", parserType).execute(context);
        new CreateDB(databaseName).execute(context);
        new List().execute(context);
        list();
    }

    private void list() throws BaseXException {
        log.fine(new List().execute(context));
    }

    public void dropCreateAdd(JSONObject tweets) throws MalformedURLException, BaseXException, JSONException {
        init();
        drop();
        create();
        add(tweets);
        list();
    }

}
```

How would I validate that the `String` of `xml` is well-formed?

Comment: You could use the XML parser to check it. For instance have a look at https://simonharrer.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/xml-validation-with-the-java-api/

Comment: I'll try that, @R.Groote -- but, at least based on the output linked above, it's obviously not even `XML`.  Yet the `JSON` is valid.

Comment: You may try underscore-java library. It has a static method U.jsonToXml(json).

Comment: https://javadev.github.io/underscore-java/ yes @ValentynKolesnikov ?

Comment: @Thufir Yes, this url.