# cannot add string to database: BaseXException: Name '' is invalid

Tags: java, json, xml, database, basex

After [adding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60035605/262852) valid `XML` from a file to `BaseX`, how do I now add valid `XML` from a `String`?

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ basex
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> list
Name                 Resources  Size    Input Path                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.w3schools.books  1          6290    https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml  
db                   1          101838                                           
twitter              0          4570                                             
w3school_data        1          5209    https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml   

4 database(s).
> 
> drop database twitter
Database 'twitter' was dropped.
> 
> exit
Have fun.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ gradle clean run

> Task :run FAILED                                                                              
/home/thufir/basex/.basex: writing new configuration file.
Feb. 03, 2020 2:23:10 A.M. basex.DatabaseHelper add
INFO: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><metadata><result_type>recent</result_type><iso_language_code>und</iso_language_code></metadata><in_reply_to_status_id_str>1223800963196162049</in_reply_to_status_id_str><in_reply_to_status_id>1223800963196162049</in_reply_to_status_id><created_at>Mon Feb 03 07:50:03 +0000 2020</created_at><in_reply_to_user_id_str>60919433</in_reply_to_user_id_str><source>&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/download/iphone&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Twitter for iPhone&lt;/a&gt;</source><retweet_count>0</retweet_count><retweeted>false</retweeted><geo>null</geo><in_reply_to_screen_name>lizardbill</in_reply_to_screen_name><is_quote_status>false</is_quote_status><id_str>1224238604437733378</id_str><in_reply_to_user_id>60919433</in_reply_to_user_id><favorite_count>0</favorite_count><id>1224238604437733378</id><text>@lizardbill  excised url</text><place>null</place><lang>und</lang><favorited>false</favorited><possibly_sensitive>false</possibly_sensitive><coordinates>null</coordinates><truncated>false</truncated><entities><urls><display_url>shop.yang2020.com</display_url><indices>15</indices><indices>38</indices><expanded_url>http://shop.yang2020.com</expanded_url><url>excised</url></urls><user_mentions><indices>0</indices><indices>11</indices><screen_name>lizardbill</screen_name><id_str>60919433</id_str><name>Bill the Lizard</name><id>60919433</id></user_mentions></entities><contributors>null</contributors><user><utc_offset>null</utc_offset><friends_count>197</friends_count><profile_image_url_https>https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1208330461518237696/GOo2AZX1_normal.jpg</profile_image_url_https><listed_count>1</listed_count><profile_background_image_url>null</profile_background_image_url><default_profile_image>false</default_profile_image><favourites_count>11211</favourites_count><description>WE NEED ALL HANDS ON DECK! #YangGang Quick-Start Guide: excised + @IowaforYang @TeamYangNH @SCforYang @NevadaforYang </description><created_at>Wed Jul 17 04:44:43 +0000 2019</created_at><is_translator>false</is_translator><profile_background_image_url_https>null</profile_background_image_url_https><protected>false</protected><screen_name>humansforyang</screen_name><id_str>1151352001579511808</id_str><profile_link_color>1DA1F2</profile_link_color><is_translation_enabled>false</is_translation_enabled><translator_type>none</translator_type><id>1151352001579511808</id><geo_enabled>false</geo_enabled><profile_background_color>F5F8FA</profile_background_color><lang>null</lang><has_extended_profile>false</has_extended_profile><profile_sidebar_border_color>C0DEED</profile_sidebar_border_color><profile_text_color>333333</profile_text_color><verified>false</verified><profile_image_url>http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1208330461518237696/GOo2AZX1_normal.jpg</profile_image_url><time_zone>null</time_zone><url>excisted</url><contributors_enabled>false</contributors_enabled><profile_background_tile>false</profile_background_tile><profile_banner_url>https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1151352001579511808/1576927762</profile_banner_url><entities><description><urls><display_url>bit.ly/welcome_to_the…</display_url><indices>56</indices><indices>79</indices><expanded_url>excised  </expanded_url><url>edited</url></urls></description><url><urls><display_url>yang2020.com/what-is-freedo…</display_url><indices>0</indices><indices>23</indices><expanded_url>https://www.yang2020.com/what-is-freedom-dividend-faq/</expanded_url><url>excised</url></urls></url></entities><statuses_count>4503</statuses_count><follow_request_sent>false</follow_request_sent><followers_count>410</followers_count><profile_use_background_image>true</profile_use_background_image><default_profile>true</default_profile><following>false</following><name>Humans for Yang </name><location>UBI FAQ </location><profile_sidebar_fill_color>DDEEF6</profile_sidebar_fill_color><notifications>false</notifications></user></root>
Exception in thread "main" org.basex.core.BaseXException: Name '' is invalid.
        at org.basex.core.Command.execute(Command.java:94)
        at org.basex.core.Command.execute(Command.java:116)
        at basex.DatabaseHelper.add(DatabaseHelper.java:83)
        at basex.DatabaseHelper.dropCreateAdd(DatabaseHelper.java:91)
        at main.App.twitterToBaseX(App.java:24)
        at main.App.main(App.java:28)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/home/thufir/.sdkman/candidates/java/12.0.1-zulu/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$                                                     
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$
```

The [constructor](http://docs.basex.org/javadoc/org/basex/core/cmd/Add.html) for Add:

> ```
> Add
>
> public Add(java.lang.String path,
>    java.lang.String input)
>
> Constructor, specifying a target path and an input.
>
> Parameters:
>     path - target path, optionally terminated by a new file name. If null, the name of the input will be set as path.
>     input - input file or XML string
> ```

code:

```
package basex;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.basex.core.BaseXException;
import org.basex.core.Context;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Add;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Open;
import org.basex.core.cmd.CreateDB;
import org.basex.core.cmd.DropDB;
import org.basex.core.cmd.List;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Set;
import org.json.XML;
import twitter4j.JSONArray;
import twitter4j.JSONException;

public class DatabaseHelper {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseHelper.class.getName());
    private Properties properties = new Properties();
    private URL url = null;
    private String databaseName = null;
    private Context context = null;
    private String parserType = null;

    private DatabaseHelper() {
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    private String wrap(String string) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        stringBuilder.append("<root>");
        stringBuilder.append(string);
        stringBuilder.append("</root>");
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void init() throws MalformedURLException, BaseXException {
        log.fine(properties.toString());
        parserType = properties.getProperty("parserType");
        url = new URL(properties.getProperty(parserType + "URL"));
        databaseName = properties.getProperty("databaseName");
        context = new Context();
        list();
    }

    private void list() throws BaseXException {
        log.fine(new List().execute(context));
    }

    private void drop() throws BaseXException {
        new Set("parser", parserType).execute(context);
        new DropDB(databaseName).execute(context);
        list();
    }

    private void create() throws BaseXException, JSONException {
        new Set("parser", parserType).execute(context);
        new CreateDB(databaseName).execute(context);
        new List().execute(context);
        list();
    }

    private void add(JSONArray tweets) throws JSONException, BaseXException {
        long id = 0L;
        String jsonStringTweet = null;
        org.json.JSONObject jsonObjectTweet = null;
        String stringXml = null;

        new Open(databaseName).execute(context);
        for (int i = 0; i < tweets.length(); i++) {
            jsonStringTweet = tweets.get(i).toString();
            jsonObjectTweet = new org.json.JSONObject(jsonStringTweet);
            stringXml = XML.toString(jsonObjectTweet);
            stringXml = wrap(stringXml);
            log.info(stringXml);
            new Add(null, stringXml).execute(context);
        }
    }

    public void dropCreateAdd(JSONArray tweets) throws MalformedURLException, BaseXException, JSONException {
        init();
        drop();
        create();
        add(tweets);
        list();
    }

}
```

I added the `wrap` method so that the resulting `String` passes [validation](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) as:

> The XML document is valid.

That being said, I'm not even sure what "Name" the error references.  Database?  The string?  Again, it works fine when passing in the path for an `XML` file -- and I **think** that I'm following the directions for this constructor to pass in a String.

Answer (score 0):

It can add the `XML` from a file as:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ ll
total 92
drwxr-xr-x  6 thufir thufir  4096 Feb  3 13:50 ./
drwxr-xr-x 22 thufir thufir  4096 Feb  1 16:05 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 thufir thufir  1979 Feb  1 21:17 build.gradle
-rw-rw-r--  1 thufir thufir   219 Feb  3 01:04 data.xml
drwxr-xr-x  8 thufir thufir  4096 Feb  3 13:50 .git/
-rw-r--r--  1 thufir thufir   427 Feb  1 16:22 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  6 thufir thufir  4096 Jan 30 00:26 .gradle/
drwxrwxr-x  3 thufir thufir  4096 Jan 30 00:24 gradle/
-rwxrwxr-x  1 thufir thufir  5916 Jan 30 00:24 gradlew*
-rw-rw-r--  1 thufir thufir  2941 Jan 30 00:24 gradlew.bat
-rw-r--r--  1 thufir thufir 35149 Jan 30 00:22 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 thufir thufir    51 Jan 30 00:22 README.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 thufir thufir   361 Jan 31 21:55 settings.gradle
drwxrwxr-x  4 thufir thufir  4096 Jan 30 00:24 src/
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ basex
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> list
Name                 Resources  Size  Input Path                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.w3schools.books  1          6290  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml  
w3school_data        1          5209  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml   

2 database(s).
> 
> exit
Enjoy life.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ gradle clean run

> Task :run
/home/thufir/basex/.basex: writing new configuration file.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$ basex
/home/thufir/basex/.basex: Unknown option 'RESTXQERRORS'.
/home/thufir/basex/.basex: writing new configuration file.
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> list
Name                 Resources  Size   Input Path                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.w3schools.books  1          6290   https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml  
twitter              15         73551                                           
w3school_data        1          5209   https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml   

3 database(s).
> 
> open twitter
Database 'twitter' was opened in 63.63 ms.
> 
> xquery /
<root>
  <metadata>
    <result_type>recent</result_type>

...

    <notifications>false</notifications>
  </user>
  <favorited>false</favorited>
</root>
Query executed in 292.16 ms.
> 
> exit
Enjoy life.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/twitterBaseX$
```

source:

```
package basex;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.basex.core.BaseXException;
import org.basex.core.Context;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Open;
import org.basex.core.cmd.CreateDB;
import org.basex.core.cmd.DropDB;
import org.basex.core.cmd.List;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Set;
import org.json.XML;
import twitter4j.JSONArray;
import twitter4j.JSONException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Add;

public class DatabaseHelper {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseHelper.class.getName());
    private Properties properties = new Properties();
    private URL url = null;
    private String databaseName = null;
    private Context context = null;
    private String parserType = null;

    private DatabaseHelper() {
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    private String wrap(String string) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        stringBuilder.append("<root>");
        stringBuilder.append(string);
        stringBuilder.append("</root>");
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void init() throws MalformedURLException, BaseXException {
        log.fine(properties.toString());
        parserType = properties.getProperty("parserType");
        url = new URL(properties.getProperty(parserType + "URL"));
        databaseName = properties.getProperty("databaseName");
        context = new Context();
        list();
    }

    private void list() throws BaseXException {
        log.fine(new List().execute(context));
    }

    private void drop() throws BaseXException {
        new Set("parser", parserType).execute(context);
        new DropDB(databaseName).execute(context);
        list();
    }

    private void create() throws BaseXException, JSONException {
        new Set("parser", parserType).execute(context);
        new CreateDB(databaseName).execute(context);
        new List().execute(context);
        list();
    }

    private void add(JSONArray tweets) throws JSONException, BaseXException, IOException {
        long id = 0L;
        String jsonStringTweet = null;
        org.json.JSONObject jsonObjectTweet = null;
        String stringXml = null;
        String fileName = "tweet.xml";

        new Open(databaseName).execute(context);
        for (int i = 0; i < tweets.length(); i++) {
            jsonStringTweet = tweets.get(i).toString();
            jsonObjectTweet = new org.json.JSONObject(jsonStringTweet);
            stringXml = XML.toString(jsonObjectTweet);
            stringXml = wrap(stringXml);
            write(stringXml,fileName);
            String stringFromFile = read(fileName);
            log.fine(stringFromFile);
            new Add(fileName, stringXml).execute(context);
        }
    }

    public void dropCreateAdd(JSONArray tweets) throws MalformedURLException, BaseXException, JSONException, IOException {
        init();
        drop();
        create();
        add(tweets);
        list();
    }

    private void write(String tweet, String fileName) throws IOException {
        log.fine(tweet);
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
        fileWriter.write(tweet);
        fileWriter.close();
    }

    private String read(String fileName) throws IOException {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return content;
    }
}
```

but that doesn't show how to add string `XML` to a database.